# no such column _id Android,Java,SQL

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm pretty new to Java and Android apps, just started several weeks ago, everything went pretty well until now, when I stuck for several hours with a problem I cannot resolve, even with checking dozens of threads here.
I'm working on pretty simple android app that is supposed to show movies and years from a database, with a possibility to add record, show them all, search by a year or title. I stopped on a problem with

> no such column _id (code 1): , while compiling SELECT _id, title, year FROM movies

I will be grateful for any help.

There are my files :

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.imdbproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView moviesList;
    Button searchYear;
    Button searchTitle;
    Button showAll;
    Button addbtn;
    Cursor cursor;
    adapter adapter_ob;
    MySQLiteHelper helper_ob;
    SQLiteDatabase db_ob;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InitDataBase();

        moviesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        searchYear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonYear);
        searchTitle =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTitle);
        addbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        showAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonShowAll);
        adapter_ob = new adapter(this);

        String[] from = { helper_ob.KEY_TITLE, helper_ob.KEY_YEAR };
        int[] to = { R.id.tv_title, R.id.tv_year };
        //PROBLEM
        //cursor = adapter_ob.queryName();
        //PROBLEM
        //SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to, 1);


        /*
        moviesList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        moviesList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
            Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            int nameId = listCursor.getInt(listCursor.getColumnIndex(helper_ob.KEY_ID));

            passdata.putInt("keyid",  nameId);
            Intent passIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,EditActivity.class);
            passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
            startActivity(passIntent);
            }
        });
        */




        addbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent addsomemoviesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddSomeMovies.class);
                startActivity(addsomemoviesIntent);
            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void InitDataBase() {
        MySQLiteHelper sqh = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

        SQLiteDatabase sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();

        long result = sqh.addMovie("movietitle", "year");

    }



}
```

**adapter.java**

```
package com.example.imdbproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class adapter {

        SQLiteDatabase database_ob;
        MySQLiteHelper openHelper_ob;
        Context context;

        public adapter(Context c)
        {
            context = c;
        }

    public adapter openToRead()
    {
        openHelper_ob = new MySQLiteHelper(context,
                MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null, MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
        database_ob = openHelper_ob.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public adapter openToWrite()
    {
        openHelper_ob = new MySQLiteHelper(context,
                MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null, MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
        database_ob = openHelper_ob.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        database_ob.close();
    }

    public long insertDetails(String title, String year)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_YEAR, year);
        openToWrite();
        long val = database_ob.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,  null,  cv);
        Close();
        return val;

    }

    public Cursor queryName()
    {
        String[] cols = { MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_TITLE,
                MySQLiteHelper.KEY_YEAR };
        openToWrite();
        Cursor c = database_ob.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,  cols,  null,  null, null, null, null);

        return c;
    }


    public Cursor queryAll(int nameId)
    {
        String[] cols = { MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_TITLE, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_YEAR };
        openToWrite();
        Cursor c = database_ob.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, cols, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID + "=" + nameId, null,null,null,null); 

        return c;
    }

}
```

**MySQLiteHelper**

```
package com.example.imdbproject;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movie_data.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "movies";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_YEAR = "year";
    public static final String SCRIPT = "Create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_TITLE
            + " text, " + KEY_YEAR + " text);";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version)
    {
        super(context, name, factory, version);

    }

    @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long addMovie(String movietitle, String year){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, movietitle);
        cv.put(KEY_YEAR, year);

        SQLiteDatabase sd = getWritableDatabase();

        long result = sd.insert(TABLE_NAME,  KEY_TITLE,  cv);
        return result;

    }

}
```

**AddSomeMovies**

```
package com.example.imdbproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddSomeMovies extends Activity {

    adapter adapter;
    MySQLiteHelper helper;
    EditText titleEdit, yearEdit;
    Button addButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_some_movies);

        titleEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        yearEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etYear);
        addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        adapter = new adapter(this);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            String titleValue = titleEdit.getText().toString();
            String yearValue = yearEdit.getText().toString();
            long val = adapter.insertDetails(titleValue, yearValue);

            finish();

        }


        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_some_movies, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonTitle"
        android:text="@string/showall"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonTitle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/yearsearch"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/titlesearch"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonShowAll"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonShowAll"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonShowAll"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:onClick="add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonYear"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonYear"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="ok"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonShowAll"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/searcheditview" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonShowAll"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/tv_title"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/tv_year"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hope this helps : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911142/android-sqlite-exception-no-such-column-id

Comment: I think you'r database not crated ,  check ddms package /data/data/database check it database created or not

Comment: From the link - rowid instead of _id helped for line <code> cursor - adapter_ob.queryName(); </code> but if I uncomment next line there comes the same problem what before.

Comment: About the database - if I open data/data/com.example.imdbproject/databases I have movie_data.db and movie_data.db-journal files.

Comment: As soon as I come back home I will check other things from given link.

Answer (score 0):

SORTED!

At least I think so. Problem disappeared when I changed database version to 2 from 1. So I can guess that it needs more attention now.

Comment: in case of someone running to this same problem, its because of on the first run, the app create the DB, and I assume that when the DB created, the author is using "id" as primary key, so when the author using cursors, the author realized that s/he need to use "_id" instead of "id", and then change it and run it. of-course that would be no column with "_id" in the DB as it was already created with "id". the solution is as described by the author to increase the DB version to trigger the DB creation, or you can uninstall the app and run it again.

Answer (score -1):

try following

```
 public static final String KEY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
```

instead of

```
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
```

Comment: Right, I've checked few times what is happening when building database.

When I set KEY_ID to "_id" it throws an error, that column _id does not exist.

When I changed it to KEY_ID = "id" it threw an error - _id does not exist... Running in circles...

Comment: I have also realised, that every single database I make has the same names in tables, even when I change KEY_... positions.